# How to put all rows at the same level in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Trying to use this query for a procedure where a client ask for a loan:

```
select loan_id,
CASE WHEN status = 'document_sent' then date ELSE NULL END as document_sent,
CASE WHEN status = 'document_rejected' then date ELSE NULL END as document_rejected
from table
and status in ('document_sent', 'document_rejected')
order by 2 asc, 3 asc
```

And this is the result:

| loan_id | document_sent | doc_rejected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 14:52 |  |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 14:57 |  |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 15:33 |  |
| 123 |  | 2021-03-01 14:54 |
| 123 |  | 2021-03-01 15:00 |
| 123 |  | 2021-03-01 15:39 |

I would like to have something like this:

| loan_id | document_sent | doc_rejected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 14:52 | 2021-03-01 14:54 |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 14:57 | 2021-03-01 15:00 |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 15:33 | 2021-03-01 15:39 |

Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: can you add the original datataable as well

Comment: How would the query know which rows to "view at the same level"? They are all for the same `loan_id`, so there does not seem to be any logic as to how they are joined together.

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is the default behavior. You can omit it.

Comment: Here very row has the same loan_id. So Its not possible to give an answer without main table data.

Answer (score -1):

If we don't make any assumptions about the absence/presence of each type of record:

```
select 
 coalesce(a.loan_id,b.loan_id) as loan_id
 , ds.date as document_sent
 , dr.date as document_rejected
from 
   (select * from tbl where status='document_sent') ds
   full outer join
   (select * from tbl where status='document_rejected') dr
   on ds.loan_id=dr.loan_id
```

If you know that one or the other status is always present, then it can be a little simplified (can be turned into `left join`), or if both records are expected to be there it can be simplified to:

```
select 
  a.loan_id
 , ds.date as document_sent
 , dr.date as document_rejected
from 
   tbl ds
   inner join
   tbl dr
   on ds.loan_id=dr.loan_id
   and ds.status='document_sent'
   and dr.status='document_rejected'
```

If `full outer join is not available:

```
select 
 coalesce(a.loan_id,b.loan_id) as loan_id
 , ds.date as document_sent
 , dr.date as document_rejected
from 
   (select * from tbl where status='document_sent') ds
   left join
   (select * from tbl where status='document_rejected') dr
   on ds.loan_id=dr.loan_id
union all
select 
 coalesce(a.loan_id,b.loan_id) as loan_id
 , ds.date as document_sent
 , dr.date as document_rejected
from 
   (select * from tbl where status='document_sent') ds
   right join
   (select * from tbl where status='document_rejected') dr
   on ds.loan_id=dr.loan_id
where ds.loan_id is null
```

Thanks @nbk for pointing out.

You could also use MIN/MAX (although we don't want to find min/max of anything, we want to take advantage of their behaviour that 1.they accept dates, and 2. they ignore null values, 3.they are used with `GROUP BY` to group rows together):

```
select 
  loan_id
 , min(case when status='document_sent' 
            then ds.date else NULL end) as document_sent
 , min(case when status='document_rejected' 
            then ds.date else NULL end) as document_rejected
from 
   tbl
group by id
```

Comment: mysql has no full outer join

Comment: The meaning of a down-vote is 'this answer is not useful' (see the tip when you hover on the down button), how is this answer not useful? In its original form it can be adjusted for a full outer join as easily as I demonstrated later by editing the answer)? I wouldn't think that the answers are useful only it just works when you copy and run.